# Add coupon to the processing order email only if the customer have not used one

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, hook-woocommerce

I came across this snippet that adds a coupon to the order mail.

I would like to make it appear in the processing order mail only if the customer have not used any coupon.

```css
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_content', 20 );

function add_content() {
echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **@update 2:  New orders** are most of the time in **`'on-hold'` status, but not in `'Processing'`.**
>   In this case, use this instead:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'processing_order_mail_message', 20 );
> function processing_order_mail_message( $order ) {
>     if ( empty( $order->get_used_coupons() ) && $order->post_status == 'wc-on-hold' )
>         echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
> }
> ```
>
> Or to **handle both `'on-hold'` AND `'processing'` statuses** use this:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'processing_order_mail_message', 20 );
> function processing_order_mail_message( $order ) {
>     if ( empty( $order->get_used_coupons() ) && ( $order->post_status == 'wc-on-hold' || $order->post_status == 'wc-processing' ) )
>         echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
> }
> ```
>
> *This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

**This code is tested and fully functional**

---

> **TESTING:**
>   To display the status of the emailed order you can add in the function this line:
>
> ```
> echo '<p>The status of this order is: ' . $order->post_status . '</p>';
> ```
>
> To display the coupons used (if they are some) add this:
>
> ```
> echo '<p>Coupons used in this order are: '; print_r( $order->get_used_coupons() ); echo '</p>'
> ```
>
> *(this is just for testing purpose).*

---

> **Original answer:**

**Yes it is possible easily** adding an **`if` statement with 2 conditions**.

The first one detect if a coupon has not been used in the order used in the order:

```
empty( $order->get_used_coupons() )
```

And the second one will detect if the order is in "processing" status:

```
$order->post_status == 'wc-processing'
```

If that conditions are matched, your message is displayed using**`'woocommerce_email_before_order_table'`** hook:

Here is your customized code snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'processing_order_mail_message', 20 );
function processing_order_mail_message( $order ) {
    if ( empty( $order->get_used_coupons() ) && $order->post_status == 'wc-processing' )
        echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

**This code is tested and fully functional**

Comment: However, I tested it with a coupon and I got an email order with the following text "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_used_coupons() on string in C:\xampp\....\Divi\functions.php on line 8527"

Comment: Sorry, now there is no error but there is no coupon in the email order either. I tried as many ways as I could come up with ...

Comment: I posted another thread regarding this issue asking how to display that coupon only in completed order mail. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975742/displaying-a-coupon-only-in-completed-order-email)