# Displaying a coupon message on emails for completed order status only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I've got [**that code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938013/3730754) that displays a coupon message in the email orders if the customer has not used any in this order.

I would like to display that coupon message only on **completed** order instead on all mails.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'processing_order_mail_message', 20 );
function processing_order_mail_message( $order ) {
    if ( empty( $order->get_used_coupons() ) && ( $order->post_status == 'wc-on-hold' || $order->post_status == 'wc-processing' ) )
        echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is possible easily** to display a custom message on emails with an **`if` statement and 2 conditions, for "complete" order status only.**

> ```
> add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'completed_order_mail_message', 20 );
> function completed_order_mail_message( $order ) {
>     if ( empty( $order->get_used_coupons() ) && $order->post_status == 'wc-completed' )
>         echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
> }
> ```
>
> *This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

**This code is tested and works perfect**

> **BUT** to **autocomplete paid orders** you need to add something:
>   [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)

Reference:

- [Add coupon to the processing order email only if the customer have not used one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937525/add-coupon-to-the-processing-order-email-only-if-the-customer-have-not-used-one/)
- [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)