# Custom message on completed order status email notification only for customer user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I would like to improve this code from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975742/displaying-a-coupon-message-on-emails-for-completed-order-status-only/38976146#38976146), to display a message on completed order status emails only for customers, but not for other user roles (as subscribers, etc...).

Here is that code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'completed_order_mail_message', 20 );
function completed_order_mail_message( $order ) {
    if ( empty( $order->get_used_coupons() ) && $order->post_status == 'wc-completed' )
        echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable this custom message on email notification for complete order status and **just for 'customer' user role**, you have to get the user data related to the order, to get the user role. Then you will use it in your conditional.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'completed_order_mail_message', 20 );
function completed_order_mail_message( $order ) {

    // Getting order user data to get the user roles
    $user_data = get_userdata($order->customer_user);

    if ( empty( $order->get_used_coupons() ) && $order->post_status == 'wc-completed' && in_array('customer', $user_data->roles) )
        echo '<h2 id="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p id="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and fully functional.